# Alternative to UIScrollVIew

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a quick question. I am trying to implement an application where the user can navigate between the screens via swipe gestures. So I am using gesture recognisers to push and pop views, the problem with that is that I don't want the transition animation to apply to the entire screen as there are certain similar components and it looks weird.

I considered using a scroll view, however I don't want to load all the controllers at the same time.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into `UIGestureRecognizer` and setting the `UIScrollView` property `delaysContentTouches` to `NO` to prevent the scroll view from consuming touch events before your gesture recognizer has the change to process the input, if you'd prefer that approach.

Don't forget that [`UIGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) offers you quite a lot of information when the gesture fires.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a scroll view and load only the visible controller. You can then look for this delegate method, and load the other controller lazily

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```